# How can i pass other data in other function in my controller to view using CI

Tags: codeigniter, templates

how can i pass a value from my query to the same view in CI. I am having a situation of like this:

```
public function index() {
  $myinfo = $this->Myprofile_model->mydata();
  $data['myinfo'] = $myinfo
  $this->load->view('header');
  $this->load->view('myprofile',$data);
  $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function getResults($id) {
 $fetchdata = $this->Myprofile_model->fetchresult($id);
 $data['userselect'] = $fetchdata;
 $this->load->view('myprofile',$data);
}
```

i already load my wholepage in index. and now i want to make another function to my button which is the `getResults($id)` function in my controller, and i want to display my another data from database to the same page. When i do the top code, my view is duplicating, because i loaded the `$this->load->view('myprofile',$data);` twice.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what exactly you want, because your question is bit confusing.

Comment: I think you want to load data in single page - like ajax...

Comment: @kishor10d can i load data in a single page without using ajax?

Comment: @JcJohn : I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

1: Create helper function and use that function on view page.

```
   OR
```

If you want records for single id then merge both function in one.
If there is many ids and you want to fetch records on click for each id then you can use ajax.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.class_name').click(function(){
            // place your code here to fetch records.
            // on success you can display the result on same page 
        })
    });
```

Comment: hello sir. thanks for answering. what i want is to load many data in single page without using ajax

Comment: You can also create helper function and call that funcion on view page .

Answer (score 0):

I am Not getting clearly but here is the controller to load multiple data on view:

```
public function index($id) {
  $myinfo = $this->Myprofile_model->mydata();
  $fetchdata = $this->Myprofile_model->fetchresult($id);

  $this->load->view('header');
  $this->load->view('myprofile',['myinfo'=>$myinfo,'fetchdata'=>$fetchdata]);
  $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

You can use

```
$this->load->view('myprofile',['myinfo'=>$myinfo,'fetchdata'=>$fetchdata,'third_data'=>$third_data.. as many as you like]);
```

Here in your code you are passing an `id` to the `getResults` function so if you would like to load the data form this function you can do the same with this function. or pass the `id` to the same index function to get the result.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir. how about the other fetchdata is located in other function not in index? something like: i have two functions

Comment: sir. is ajax recommended for every codeigniter retrieving data? . . or maybe it is just used for stop refreshing the page?

Comment: Ajax is a luxury to have but use it every time is not what i recommend.  You have to decide  upon what functionality you are doing.

Comment: I am adding some example related your question in this answer so you can see and decide where to use ajax.

Comment: thanks for reply sir. . is it good if i use all ajax?.. that's why i am learning how to get data's without using ajax/javascript in other function but loaded in one data because i don't want to use ajax again and again

Comment: Please Accept or upvote if my suggestions are helping you to solve your problem. @JcJohn